# : MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, mongodb-.net-driver

So, I am using `MongoDB` on a `Azure VM` and I have a web site hosted on Azure web Sites as a service. 
My problem is: Sometimes I get an error like this:

> "Exception: MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

After I got this error, just I access the endpoint again and I have success immediately.

Details:

> ConnectionString: mongodb://xxx.aaa.net:1000, xxx.aaa.net:1001, xxx.aaa.net:1002/?readPreference=nearest

Before open the conection with Mongo I set the MaxConnectioIdleTimeout property like this "MongoDefaults.MaxConnectionIdleTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);" , To keep alive connection, because the idle timeout for azure LoadBalancer become inactivy after 4 minutes by default.

So, I don't know what's going on.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, 4 minutes. Azure closes a connection session if it keeping on idling up to 4 minutes.But the mongodb driver don't know it，it will still get this connection form connection pool.
You can either set the **MaxConnectionIdleTime**(in mongodb driver settings) less than 4 minutes, or set the max session idle time of azure VM more larger by powershell (30 minutes max).

BTW, if your web site which also hosted on azure access the mongodb server with the private IP(PIP), there won't be this problem.

Comment: I didn't know about Azure closing the connection if idle for more than 4 minutes.
Where I can I find that documentation?
On the other hand, in my case, I don't have a VM. It's hosted on Azure on an App Service. Do you know if the same policy applies and if that so how to set the max session on an Ap Service?

Answer (score 0):

As I asked @apodemakels for some official documentation, I have found [MongoDB Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#azure) where it states:
*The TCP idle timeout on the Azure load balancer is 240 seconds by default, which can cause it to silently drop connections if the TCP keepalive on your Azure systems is greater than this value. You should set tcp_keepalive_time to 120 to ameliorate this problem.*

In addition, there's a [ticket on MongoDB Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1303) with regard to this issue.

I hope both these documents may help with this or in case someone faces a similar situation.