# Error UpdateOne, ReplaceOne and DeleteMany with MongoDB c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

Repetitive errors when trying to execute any of these commands, UpdateOne, ReplaceOne and DeleteMany

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Mensaje = An exception occurred while opening a connection to the
>   server.   Origen = MongoDB.Driver.Core   Seguimiento de la pila:    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.ConnectionPools.ExclusiveConnectionPool.AcquiredConnection.Open(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.GetChannel(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ServerChannelSource.GetChannel(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Bindings.ChannelSourceHandle.GetChannel(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteContext.Create(IWriteBinding
>   binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
>   en
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.BulkMixedWriteOperation.Execute(IWriteBinding
>   binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteBinding
>   binding, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle
>   session, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IClientSessionHandle
>   session, IEnumerable`1 requests, BulkWriteOptions options,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.b__0(IClientSessionHandle
>   session)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.BulkWrite(IEnumerable`1 requests,
>   BulkWriteOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.<>c__DisplayClass94_0.<UpdateOne>b__0(IEnumerable`1
>   requests, BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.UpdateOne(FilterDefinition`1
>   filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, UpdateOptions options, Func`3
>   bulkWrite)    en
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionBase`1.UpdateOne(FilterDefinition`1
>   filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, UpdateOptions options,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    en
>   DataManager.UpdateElements.<>c__DisplayClass86_0.<UpdateTransferSwitches>b__0(TransferSwitch
>       en
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass31_0`2.b__0(Int32
>   i)    en
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__1()

the line of code that crashes in a parallel. ForEach (), in a class method

```
var BsonData = new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {"ICurrent", Math.Round(transferSwitch.ICurrent,1)},
                        {"Load", load},
                    };
                var filterId = new BsonDocument("_id", transferSwitch.Id);
                var updateTransferSwitch = new BsonDocument("$set", BsonData);
                transferSwitchesCollection.UpdateOne(filterId, updateTransferSwitch);
```

in other class method is the DeleteMany

```
var filterDelete = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Not(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("GUIDUpdate", guidUpdate));
                    maintenancesCollection.DeleteMany(filterDelete);
```

and the ReplaceOne is in the same method and same Parallel.ForEach

```
                if (maintenance.Value.Show)
                {
                    maintenance.Value.GUIDUpdate = guidUpdate;
                    var filterId = new BsonDocument("_id", maintenance.Value.Id);
                    var bsonData = maintenance.Value.ToBsonDocument();

                    maintenancesCollection.ReplaceOne(filterId, bsonData, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
                }
```

how can I fix those errors?

**Update**
For this I use the 2.1 Version of mongoDB.Driver

Comment: I can barely read your stacktrace. Can you reformat it? Also, are you using `bulkWrite` (I see mentions in yourstack trace)? If you are using BulkWrite then ensure you also log the BulkWriteException detials.

Comment: @RobertSeaman thanks for your answer, make a BulwriteException that is Obsolete https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.11/html/904d71f7-ae20-2ea4-a47c-093fffdd5c08.htm I'm using version 2.1 of mongo DB

Comment: Apologies, I'm not familiar with the c# api. I see `An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server`. Is it possible the server was down at this point? Searching for that error might lead you to an answer.. maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34817834/connection-issue-from-latest-net-mongodb-driver/35411479 , or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385566

Comment: Is it possible the server was down? No! I use this piece of code  to check if the mogo is live----> bool isMongoLive = DataSource.MongoDataBase.RunCommandAsync((